# How to send drafts content to makeslides using callback URL

Tags: ipad, markdown, powerpoint, callbackurl

I am using drafts 5 and would like to convert the markdown into a powerpoint using a callback URL action. It appears like it should be quite straightforwards but Im not getting any success using the following:

```
makeslides://x-callback-url?input=[[draft]]&type=md&name=mydoc
```

I just keep getting an error message saying invalid URL generated. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it working when I do two steps, first copy to clipboard and second use the callback URL to makeslides

```
makeslides://x-callback-url?input=[[clipboard]]&type=md&name=[[title]]
```